# How to parse and sum comma separated string of numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have problem with reading my data from JSON.

This is my controller:

```
myApp.controller("abcdctrl", ['$scope', 'orderByFilter', '$http', function ($scope, orderBy, $http) {
console.log('abcdctrl');
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/session")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data.session;
    });

$scope.getAvg = function () {
    var total = Number("0");
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        total += parseInt($scope.data[i].testing);
    }
    return parseInt(total / $scope.data.length);
}
}]);
```

This is my JSON

```
{
"session": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "testing": "91,92,93,94,95,96,97",
        "playing": "11,12,13,14,15,16,17",
        "acc_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "testing": "101,102,103,104,105,106,107",
        "playing": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7",
        "player_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "testing": "111,112,113,114,115,116,117",
        "playing": "21,22,23,24,25,26,27",
        "acc_id": 3
    }
]
}
```

I want to calculate the average value of each player for tasting and playing, and I want to calculate the total average value for testing and playing. I succeed in printing the entire JSON, but I have problems accessing an element in JSON.

Thanks for your help

Comment: where is this `$scope.getAvg` function is call ? you have testing value with `,` seperator , it is not possible to add .

Comment: no it's not possible to add . , getAvg is calling in html

Comment: `91,92,93,94,95,96,97` + `101,102,103,104,105,106,107` this is not possible

Comment: `parseInt("4") -> 4`. `parseInt("4,3,2,1,5,6,7") -> 4`.  You are trying to use `parseInt` to parse an array of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
myApp.controller("abcdctrl", ['$scope', 'orderByFilter', '$http', function ($scope, orderBy, $http) {
console.log('abcdctrl');
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/session")
    .then( function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data.session;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
 });

$scope.getAvg = function () {
    var total = Number("0");
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
       var grades = $scope.data[i].testing.split(',');
       for(var j = 0; j < grades.length; j++){
           total += parseInt(grades[j]);
       }
    }
    return parseInt(total / $scope.data.length);
}
}]);
```